# HTML to PDF convertor in Laravel5?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, laravel-5

I want to generate PDF file from a view in laravel5. I found https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf and added to my project via composer.

but it is not working,

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice', array());
 return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Getting error is

```
ErrorException in InvoiceController.php line 34: Non-static method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::loadView() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

Is there any other package for laravel5?

Comment: You need to use the facade, you can simply add a backslash like this \PDF::loadView()

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf');
$pdf->loadView('invoice', array());
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Regards

Comment: getting error is `Argument 1 passed to Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository, none given,`

Comment: how can add external style sheet ?

Comment: Just add a link to the external stylesheet in HTML...
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/www/test/css_at_font_face.html

Answer (score 0):

I worked with 2 method for HTML to PDF 
   1.MPDF
   2.Snappy PDF developed using WKHTML to PDF
Follow those 2 url you can use them using composer require.It will definitely help
For SNAPPY:http://www.kingpabel.com/php-html-to-pdf-snappy/ 
For MPDF:http://www.kingpabel.com/mpdf-for-php-to-pdf/

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function export(PDF $pdf, Student $students) {
   $students= $students->all();
    //  $brand = Brands::all();//todo: sort folder and conrtoller
    $results=[];
    $pdf = $pdf->loadView('dashboard.strs.manage.reports.examreports.exampdfreport',compact('students'));
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

> This method loads the pdf dialog box allows you to save your file as you would prefer.